# Wrong "Asked: x years/months/days ago" calculation

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, timestamps

On my question asked around 2 years ago :

[Why are nested loops considered bad practice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/199196/why-are-nested-loops-considered-bad-practice)

To the right of the question title it said that the question was asked a year ago. Why is that?

[image: image showing the issue]

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't think it's a duplicate. I understand that it's difficult to show correctly when we're talking about "today/yesterday" due to time zones etc. My question is regarding the fact that even after 1 year and 300+ days it still shows as "Asked 1 year ago".

Comment: Still, same principle applies in both.

Comment: The other question might be same principal, but the other question is never going to answer this one unless someone expands from "today" and "24 hours" to go on about months and years. Given it's a 3 year old question, I doubt that will happen.

Comment: @James Exactly. If this question gets closed due to being a duplicate it doesn't make sense at all. The other question and its answer does not answer my question. It's not a duplicate!

Answer (score 2):

Because it hasn't been asked 2 years ago yet.

The date it was asked was 2013-05-23 19:56:00Z. Since it's not May 23rd, 2015 yet and the sidebar only gives approximations, it's correct. It will update itself next month to say that it was asked 2 years ago.

Comment: I just find it odd that it says "Asked 1 year ago". I think it's a bit misleading. It should say asked more than one year ago or something similar.

Comment: how about "asked `(int)(x/365.25)` years ago" where `x` is the number of days since the question was asked?

Comment: It's pretty inaccurate then. So basically, it only increments in years? So it will only count the current year when it's over? i.e. shows "1 year" for  729 days?